# Unable to return a file using FileProvider in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, fileprovider

I have two Xamarin Forms Android apps. App1 creates an activity in App2, that creates files that should be returned to App1.

Previously I was using the same sharedUserId in AndroidManifest.xml of both apps so it was simply needed to return the file path.

But sharedUserID is obsolete and incompatible with Microsoft Defender per app vpn, so it's not an option anymore.

The AndroidManifest.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="App2.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.companyname.app2.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

The file_paths.xml is this:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Below is a test code in App2 MainActivity that creates a file, create a uri, read the file using the uri and try to share the uri. As you can see in the code, I was not sure which context should I use so I tried many options.

```
        private void test()
        {
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(builder.Build());

            string savefilePath = Path.Combine($"{Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("")}", "test1.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savefilePath, "Hello from FileProvider 2!");
            _file = new Java.IO.File(savefilePath);
            Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            //Context context = this;
            //Context context = this.ApplicationContext;
            //Context context = MainApplication.CurrentContext;
            Android.Net.Uri contentUri = MyFileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.companyname.app2.fileprovider", _file);

            using (var contentResolver = this.ContentResolver)
            using (var inputStream = contentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(contentUri.ToString())))
            {
                if (inputStream != null)
                {
                    // Read the content from the inputStream here
                    // For example, you could use a StreamReader to read text-based content

                    byte[] buffer;

                    buffer = new byte[40000 * 2];
                    int bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"Read {bytesRead} from the file"); // it works as expected
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Failed to open input stream for URI");
                }
            }

            var shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            shareIntent.SetType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, contentUri);
            shareIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(shareIntent, "Share file"), RequestCode);
        }
```

If I select WhatsApp, it crashes.
If I select GMail, it creates an e-mail with text1.txt attached, showing the correct size of 26 bytes, but can't download it.

The MainApplication code is this, as suggested in another StackOverflow post:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace App2.Droid
{
    [Application]
    public partial class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    {
        internal static Context CurrentContext { get; private set; }

        internal static String FileProviderAuthority
        {
            get => MainApplication.CurrentContext.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".fileprovider";
        }

        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        }

        public override void OnTerminate()
        {
            base.OnTerminate();
            UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        }

        public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            CurrentContext = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
        {

        }

        public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
        {

        }

        public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
        {
            CurrentContext = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
        {

        }

        public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
        {
            CurrentContext = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I copy/pasted the uri to App1 and used the same reading code with contentResolver.OpenInputStream but it either had a permission problem, or couldn't find the content provider or returned file not found.

I found lot of posts using Uri.FromFile, java code, old Xamarin/Android code, but nothing is working.

I know that there is a Xamarin.Essentials FileProvider class but couldn't find any sample.

I need to return to App1 file uris inside the json result of an activity in App2.

I use the code below to return the result:

```
var rtn = new Intent();
string json = "...somthing with uri files...";
rtn.PutExtra("result", json);
SetResult(Result.Ok, rtn);
Finish();
```

The uri's are returned as expected but I can't read the files.

Comment: Why are you talking about WhatsApp and GMail where in the first lines of your post you wanna provide files for App1?

Comment: Probably you should add a `<queries>` tag in the manifest file of App1.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, thanks for trying to help. I shared the uri to WhatsApp and Gmail just to check if any other app would be able to read the file, and they couldn't.

Comment: Did you try to share the file in the public folder instead of the app's own file?

Comment: Today everything is working as expected.
The most relevant thing I've done was to restart the phone.